# is there an option to select which series to show in multiple series highstock

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a highstock multiple line series, but there are lot of series like around 50 in number. So, all 50 i can not show in one single chart so is there a way in which i can give an option to select which of the series to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a legend in which all the categories are labelled. This will enable you to remove groups by clicking on the category name.

```
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/